# Replacing of regular Expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

I am trying to replace the word "test" with some special characters.

```
   <p id="demo">Visit test</p> 

   var res = str.replace("test", "@$&*");
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
```

But it's displaying output as  " Visit @test* " .Anyone guide me to get output as " Visit @$&* " ?

Comment: Suresh, you do not need to use any callbacks inside the `replace()` method, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43502597/3832970) to learn how to achieve that with in a shorter way.

Answer (score 2):

The `$&` sequence inside a replacement pattern denotes a *backreference* to the *whole match value*. That is why your `@t$&*` replacement turns into `@` + the match value equal to `test` + `*`.

To replace with a dollar symbol, you can do it without any callbacks, just double the `$` symbol (dollar-escape it) in the replacement pattern:

```js
var str = "Visit test";
var res = str.replace("test", "@$$&*");
console.log(res);
```

See MDN ["Specifying a string as a parameter"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

> `$$`   Inserts a `"$"`.

Answer (score 1):

[Check the live example](http://jsfiddle.net/j9orwbk5/) just need to change `str.replace("test", () => "@$&*");`

```
var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
var res = str.replace("test", () => "@$&*");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
```

Comment: what exactly is () => doing? I was not aware of it. That is a nice trick

Comment: This prevent automatic regex substitution

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
var res = str.replace("test", '@$');
res = res.concat('&*');
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
```

Comment: Code-only answers do very little to educate SO readers.  Your answer may or may not be a correct answer, but it is in the moderation queue after being marked as "low-quality".  Please take a moment to improve your answer with an explanation.